# step by step procedure to connect to the thingspeak

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I am new to Arduino and I am using Arduino Uno r3. I have to upload the temperature sensor data to ThingSpeak. For that I am using DHT11. For connectivity of WiFi I am using ESP8266. Could you please me how to upload the sensor value to ThingSpeak?

Comment: i don't see why you need an uno for that; the dht11 (alone or as a module) works well with ESPs and eliminating the complication also saves a lot of money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instructable -- looks like a perfect match:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Send-sensor-data-DHT11-BMP180-to-ThingSpeak-with-a/

Rob Purser

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend that you just use the ESP8266 (specifically the NodeMCU) as it is both a WiFi device and microcontroller.

You can use the Arduino IDE to program the NodeMCU. If this is the case, then all you have to do create a WiFiClient, then construct an HTTP POST request, and send it to ThingSpeak using the client.

Here are the relevant lines from my [tutorial](http://nothans.com/measure-wi-fi-signal-levels-with-the-esp8266-and-thingspeak):

Before your setup add the lines:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
WiFiClient client;
const char* server = "api.thingspeak.com";
String writeAPIKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

In your loop, add the following lines to read A0 and send it to ThingSpeak:

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {

    // Measure Analog Input (A0)
    int valueA0 = analogRead(A0);

    // Construct API request body
    String body = "field1=";
           body += String(valueA0);

    Serial.print("A0: ");
    Serial.println(valueA0); 

    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: " + writeAPIKey + "\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(body.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.print(body);
    client.print("\n\n");

}
client.stop();

// wait 20 seconds and post again
delay(20000);
```